# React useSelector how to use in functions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

Iam setting up a global headers for the axios (React Native) so i need to get token from the redux store. But when i try to get it throws error: Invalid hook call

Anyother way around or solutions would be a big help!

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

let authToken;

function getToken() {
  authToken = useSelector(state => state?.authReducer?.authToken);
  return;
} getToken();
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot you useSelector in function.
But you can get state by using following syntax.

```
const state = store.getState()
```

and then you can get your desired values like

```
let authToken = state?.authReducer?.authToken;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are for functional components (*.jsx) and not for functions (*.js).

Use `getState()` instead of useSelector.